# Confused wpf grid behaviour in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I am confused about the Grid's behaviour inside a ContentTemplate:

I want to style my ListView:

```
   <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
     <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArticleID}"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArticleName}"
               Grid.Column="1"
               />
    <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveComponentFromVehicle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        >
        <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource IconTextCombo}">
                <Image Source="{StaticResource ComponentToVehicle_Delete}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
   </Grid>
```

As you can see, I want to make sure that my buttons align right on the right side because the ArticleID and Name length can vary.

The buttons aren't align as I want and expect. I have a test project:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="Foo" 
             Grid.Column="0"/>
    <TextBox Text="Bar"
             Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Button Content="DELETE"
            Grid.Column="2"/>
    <TextBox Text="Hello World" 
             Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox Text="LONG TEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXT"
             Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Button Content="DELETE"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

In this 'hardcoded' version every aligns as I want... I don't know why my grid is so weird in the Template. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you meant to set the template in `ContentTemplate` and not `ItemTemplate`?

Comment: @GrayFox it does not sound weird when all 3 columns have width set to Auto which will make them auto adjust to content width. Also if you want content of `ListViewItem` to stretch you need to set `HorizontalContentAlignment` in `ItemContainerStyle`

Comment: @MotiAzu there is no ItemTemplate... Only ContentTemplate

Comment: @dkozl HorizontalContentAlignment = "stretch" doesn't work to solve my problem...

Comment: @GrayFox `ListView` definitely has an `ItemTemplate` property. If you set it instead of `ContentTemplate` there is a good chance your problem will be fixed. It looks like you are trying to bind to your item's proerties via `ContentTemplate`, which makes no sense.

Comment: @MotAzu if I set:

ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComponentInVehicleListView}"

An object of the type "System.Windows.Style" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Windows.DataTemplate"

Comment: @GrayFox bacause all columns width is set to auto. Try removing width restriction on the middle column for example

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the `SharedSizeGroup` property on your grid in your template. It works in your hardcoded example because all your elements sit inside the same grid. Once you place them inside a ListBox every item has its own grid and is unaware of the other grids. 
Setting this property will make sure all these columns have the same size regardless which grid they are in.

your Grid.ColumnsDefinitions should look like this:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
  <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" SharedSizeGroup="ColumnA"/> 
  <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" SharedSizeGroup="ColumnB"/> 
  <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" SharedSizeGroup="ButtonsColumn"/> 
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

---

You should also use ItemTemplate meaning:

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
*****Your Posted Code ************
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: what do you mean with 'ButtonsColumn' ? Sorry for that but I am a total beginner in WPF

Comment: Its just a string you could write "David" and it will work. The layout algorithm of WPF makes sure that each column marked with the same string will be the same size.

Comment: okay, thank you... But it doesn't work. I will post my whole code now

Comment: With the two column in front auto the third is not going to line up.

Comment: @Blam Thats also true they should be * or have SharedSizeGroup

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution after working around:

```
   <ListView DockPanel.Dock="Right"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding }"
          Name="lvMain"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
          >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArticleID}"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArticleName}"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       />
                    <Button Command="{Binding }"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                >
                        <Button.Content>
                            <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource IconTextCombo}">
                                <Image Source="{StaticResource img}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I have tested it with ListBox and ListView... It works for both of them as I want now!

Thanks to all helpers!

Comment: @Amit I use ListBox now and follow your update... But it doesn't work.

Comment: I have updated my answer and added The SharedSizeGroup to all columns. This should work for you